# grep names in a small file matching a large file

Tags: bash, grep

My small file contains this information line by line:

```
abc.123
abc.258
abc.952
```

I wanted to get those lines matching in my bigger file (~30Gb). I tried this command but it didn't give me any result.

```
grep -f small.txt big.txt
```

I have tested all `abc.123`, `abc.258` and `abc.952` does exist in my bigger file, meaning that I tried to grep each of these names one by one it gave me the exact result I want.

```
grep "abc.123" big.txt
```

I have no idea where I could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Add output of `file small.txt` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Your `small.txt` may have DOS line endings. If so, fix it with [dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/).

Comment: @tshiono thank you, after converting, it works perfectly. is there a way to avoid this happening when creating a txt file? I built via nano btw

Comment: `cat -A` will show line ending characters on the screen. I'm not so familiar
with `nano` but it will notice the file is in `DOS Format` when reading
and writing. You can toggle the mode with keying `Meta-D` or `Alt-D`.

Comment: You can use `dos2unix some_file.txt` to change the line endings.